# Extract dataLayer using flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

Using a standard WebView you can get the dataLayer like this
final dataLayer = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('dataLayer');

Does anyone know how to get the same using flutter_inappwebview?

Controller of flutter_inappwebview does not have the runJavaScriptReturnResult function.